# How can I reprogram a USB "easy button"?

Tags: microcontroller

I have a USB "easy button"- is a USB cable attached to a large button. It appears as a keyboard to the computer. When I push the button, it sends the keys Start+R and then quickly types in a pre-configured URL. I am fairly certain that the company that produces these buttons sets the URL via some sort of software over USB. How could I reprogram the button myself? What sort of software would I need?

Here is a link to the website: http://www.usbsmartbuttons.com/

Comment: Like this? http://solid-orange.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/easy_button.jpg

Comment: i added a link to the actual button

Comment: It depends. Crack open the device. See if there is a jtag you can use. What kind of microcontroller does it use? Does it have some external EEPROM you can flash(as in, outside the CPU)? Can you find a datasheet or anything on the device?

Comment: This is the most useless thing I've ever seen (except the iPad, that's on another league of uselessness).

Comment: it's a cheap marketing gimmick. in that sense, they're rather useful

Comment: Dear people of 2013: BTW, [USBButton](http://www.usbbutton.com/) by Ultimarc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [forum thread](http://www.hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1312818), the device is probably the same.

Comment: I wonder what USB class they are using. Is it an HID? How can the hardware run a script on Windows without custom drivers?

Answer (score 2):

The "Easy button" is most likely a USB Human Interface Device (HID) keyboard class. By conforming to strict HID specifications the firmware programed into the micro controller the button can function without installing any drivers much like a USB mouse, keyboard or any other USB device that instantly recognizes after immediately plugging in. If you're interested http://www.lvr.com/hidpage.htm is a great start.

Comment: cool, it's a lot to take in but i cant wait to get it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case Someone else finds this thread: If you are looking for ways to integrate such a button with your own application, the easiest approach would be to have them trigger a very uncommon keyboard combination (something like Alt-Ctrl-Shift-O) and catch with a system-wide keyboard hook in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little bit of research on that and found out that there are different types out there. Sophisticated ones which can be hacked in the sense that you can e.g. change the URL but also cheap ones that are hard coded.

In the case of the latter one not all is lost: What I did is make use of a redirection tool (like this one: http://requestly.in/) and use the dongle as a foot pedal to start a tea timer (https://www.google.com/search?q=timer+3+minutes).

So I now literally trample on the logo of a company that ruins the environment with this kind of electronic waste ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Or this site too http://www.wonderhowto.com/how-to-hack-staples-easy-button-18413/

I saw something, somewhere, awhile ago, that I can't now find about someone repurposing it to start a build.

Comment: it was someone using big red dome button with arduino to make a java build.http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvpyrrWtWR8